# Popup not opening when icon is clicked html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this popup that I want to open when the user clicks on the share icon. It should say copied

Here is the HTML

```html
<div class="copy-text">
  <a>
    <div class="mini-button mini_button_2"><img src="/images/share.svg" alt="share" /></div>
  </a>
  <div class="popup">Copied</div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS

```css
.copy-text .popup {
  content: "copied";

  position: absolute;
  top: -45px;
  right: 0px;
  background: #5c81dc;
  padding: 8px 10px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  font-size: 15px;
  display: none;
}

.copy-text .popup:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  right: 25px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #5c81dc;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  display: none;
}

.copy-text.active .popup:before,
.copy-text.active .popup {
  display: block;
}
```

Here is the javascript

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var button = document.querySelector('.mini_button_2');
  var copyText = document.querySelector('.copy-text');

  button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    copyText.classList.add('active');
    setTimeout(function() {
      copyText.classList.remove('active');
    }, 2500);
  });
});
```

However, when I click the icon, nothing shows up. What is the problem?

I want something like this to show up
[image]

Comment: you use `position:relative` for parent? because you give popup `top:-45` and that means it is outside of page, and also `content` property for `:before` and `:after` NOT for `.popup` element

Comment: I don't understand what to change

- Thanks, :)

Comment: I'm sorry for that, `content` property it is for Pseudo Element only (::after, ::before) not for any class, so you should type it in `::before` instead,

number 2: `position:absolute` that you gave it to element, you should give `position:relative` for its parent, otherwise the element will be float on web page and outside its boundary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It showed but it's show outside the window because now the popup div is related to the body. just add position:relative to copy-text.

add I also believe use should change top:-20px in ::before to be button: -4px.